# Rails : Analytics/Reporting Tool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reporting, analytics

I have an application with reporting feature where user can go query for my data. 
As of now, I have written all the code to create the dynamic queries based on user's criteria and then run those queries in the data base and show it to the user.

What I need is a reporting tool, to which I will just give my data/database , and it will be provide an interface to run reports on.

My application is a Ruby on Rails application.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [rails-data-explorer (RDE)](https://github.com/jhund/rails-data-explorer). RDE is a Rails engine plugin that makes it magically easy to explore your app's data using charts and statistics.